# Validating a list of values in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my model I have a field which should contain only the values 'A', 'B' and 'C'. Would this be best use for using a `choice` parameter when declaring the field?

If I didn't decide to use the `choice` parameter and wanted to write custom validation logic for it, where would I write this — would this be in the `clean` method of the model? I've also seen `clean_<fieldname>` methods — what are these for or doe they only apply to forms? I would like to do this validation in the model as I'm not using a form.

```
class Action(models.Model):
    """
    Contains the logic for the visit
    """
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=65535, null=False)
    to = models.IntegerField(null=False)

    def clean(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Custom clean method to do some validation
        """
        #Ensure that the 'to' is either 1,2 or 3.
        if self.to not in [0, 1, 2]:
            raise ValidationError("Invalid to value.")
```

When I'm doing validation, do I need to return some value? Will my method method be called when someone creates a new record?

(Although I've read the docs, I'm still a little confused about this.)

Thanks a ton.

Comment: I would recommend reading this blog:  http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/02/handle-choices-right-way/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you gave, I would use the `choice` parameter. If you put the validation for `to` field in the clean method, then any errors will be associated with the action instance and not the `to` field.

As you stated, `clean_<fieldname>` methods are for form fields. On the model, you can define [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/).

Here's an example of your clean method rewritten as a validator.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_to(value):
    """
    Ensure that the 'to' is either 1, 2 or 3.
    """
    if value not in [1, 2, 3]:
        raise ValidationError("Invalid 'to' value.")

class Action(models.Model):
    """
    Contains the logic for the visit
    """
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=65535, null=False)
    to = models.IntegerField(null=False,validators=[validate_to])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want it to be 'A', 'B', and 'C', you should definitely use Django's built in validation instead of rolling your own. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/ in the section titled `choices`.

In brief:

```
class Action(models.Model):
    """
    Contains the logic for the visit
    """

    TO_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'Choice 0'),
        (1, 'Choice 1'),
        (2, 'Choice 2'),
    )
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=65535, null=False)
    to = models.IntegerField(null=False, choices=TO_CHOICES)
```